# JPA implementation that doesn't require no-arg constructor

Tags: java, jpa, default-constructor

Is there an ORM framework which implements JPA but doesn't require default 
(no-arg) constructor from `@Entity` classes?

AFAIK, it is said in JPA documentation that an `@Entity` should have default 
constructor, but can an implementation support constructor arguments injection 
(or maybe unsafe object instantiation) and therefore work with classes without
 a default constructor?

This feature would help a lot to ensure immutability (which *standard* JPA lacks) 
and would let the developer keep strict invariants on class instance state 
(e.g. its fields always have the correct value).

By the way, when using Kotlin, the need of no-arg constructor interferes with
good code style and coding conventions.

There's `JIRM` library which deals with constructor injection and immutability,
but it's not a complete JPA implementation.

So, does any of the JPA ORMs support `@Entity` classes with no default constructor?

Comment: I'm new to it so forgive me if I'm misunderstanding your question; seems straight forward though. I have `@Entity`s in a Spring app with no default no-arg constructors and seems to be working fine.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, do I get it right that your `@Entity` classes have constructors with arguments? If they don't then they have default constructors generated implicitly.

Comment: It is typical for frameworks which need to be able to create object instances of your supplied classes to require a no-arg constructor.  Reflectively invoking arbitrary constructors would be difficult since, in the general case, a framework can't predict what arguments would need to be supplied to a given constructor (even if it could reflectively learn the number of types of parameters).  JPA does not forbid you to use constructors that take arguments, but if you do define one you must also make sure there is an accessible no-arg constructor.

Comment: See, I knew I misunderstood it. I thought you meant you're being forced to implement explicit ones in the absence of others.

Comment: @scottb, it seems not that difficult to me if the implementation would require the correct naming (though, I agree, getting parameter names is not always possible) or annotating the constructor parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there an ORM framework which implements JPA but doesn't require default (non-arg) constructor from @Entity classes?

No, because it would break the specification. The below quote is from page 23 of the [*JPA 2.1* specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html):

> The entity class must have a no-arg constructor. The entity class may have other constructors as well. The no-arg constructor must be public or protected.

Having said that, there might exist some ORM framework that implements JPA partially that ignores this feature.

Comment: Thanks, I doubted if the requirement must be forced by the implementations or they just have to work correctly in the cases specified but still can weaken it and support broader use cases.

Comment: @hotkey I understand what you are saying. However, I think an ORM framework like Hibernate, which implements JPA, rather adds functionality (annotations etc). I suspect that it doesn't do anything that breaks the spec. So, I still think that not implementing this requirement would break the spec, hence make it not implement JPA fully.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tried with EclipseLink 2.5.2 and even if its not provided, works fine.